# angular2 update template of one component from click event of another component

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, angular, components

I have developed an app in angular2 where one component(component-bar) displays list of thumbnails of the angular2 components by reading a json Object.

I have added `click event` which will pass the component name to click event function `clicked(comp.name)`  and prints the name of the component on console.

Now I want to render the component whose thumbnail has been clicked in the template of another component(designer).
I have designed these components in different folder and to generated thumbnails I have created below JSON object.

```
"components": [
  {
      "name":"HeadingComponent",
      "desc":"",
      "cmpType":"Standard",
      "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/ABC_bank.png",
      "cmpLocation":"components/heading/heading.component.ts",
      "isDynamic":"true"          
  },
  {
      "name":"BodyComponent",
      "desc":"",
      "cmpType":"Standard",
      "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/demoairline.png",
      "cmpLocation":"components/heading/body.component.ts",
      "isDynamic":"true" 
  },
  {
      "name":"FooterComponent",
      "desc":"",
      "cmpType":"Standard",
      "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/SCE_5.PNG",
      "cmpLocation":"components/heading/footer.component.ts",
      "isDynamic":"true" 
  }    
]
```

current UI of app is as displayed in the image:

[image: app to load components from thumbnails]

Below is the code for my app:

**component-bar.html**

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="searchComp" type="text" placeholder="Search Components..." />
<div id="sidebar-scroll" *ngIf="record != undefined">
    <div class="text-xs-bold" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0px; height:100%">
        <ul style="background-color:transparent;overflow: hidden">
            <li *ngFor="#comp of record.components | search:searchComp:true" style="display:block;padding:0px;cursor:move;position:relative;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px"
        title="{{comp.name}}">
                <p class="text-center h6" style="font-size:8px;color:blue;font-weight:bold;"> {{comp.name }}</p>
                <img class="img-thumbnail1" src="{{comp.imgUrl}}" style="max-width:100%;" (click)="clicked(comp.name)">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component-bar.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'component-bar',
pipes:[SearchPipe],
providers: [DragulaService],
directives: [Dragula],
templateUrl: 'app/designer/component-bar/component-bar.component.html'
})

export class ComponentBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() record: Object;        
    constructor() {    
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //console.log(this.record);
    }

    clicked(compName) {
        console.log(compName);//this prints component name correctly
    }

}
```

I tried integrating ng2-dragula module to provide drag and drop functionality too.but could not get any success.

I searched for lot of articles but couldnt find anything useful.
is there any module or working demo for the feature that I am trying to develop?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Er. I think you can try this anwser .
[Angular2 how to call function on click event from another component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272031/angular2-how-to-call-function-on-click-event-from-another-component/43272555#43272555)

Comment: Er . I think u can try this anwser.
[Angular2 how to call function on click event from another component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272031/angular2-how-to-call-function-on-click-event-from-another-component/43272555#43272555)